# Posibility of implement trusted HTTPS in localhost (xampp)

Tags: apache, xampp, ssl-certificate

is it possible to have a verified certificate for xampp localhost? I able to navigate to https in localhost but i got this error "Connection is not secure".

[image]
I want something like this when i navigate to localhost.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: please explain for the down vote.

Comment: I don't know why your question was downvoted, but the only sensible answer for now is to learn a lot more about certificates and CAs. A definitive answer is too broad. You are asking for an EV cert. No CA will issue you an EV cert for localhost. To get the result you want requires expertise way beyond what you've demonstrated here.

Answer (score -1):

you can use self-signed certificate, but it might work only with edge, the latest versions of major browsers didn't trust self-signed certificates, you can navigate to "Security" section in "Developer Tools" to see the exact error.

want to see an example? see this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0kvOQJj7gVk

but it won't work if you use updated browser.